# Why as3 giving me syntax error in a for loop?

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, flash, for-loop, actionscript

I'm new with actionscript and I keep getting syntax error with the following for loop:

```
for each (target:Target in targets) {
  if(target != null) {
    target.parent.removeChild(target);
  }
}
```

And I got this error message:

```
Syntax error: expecting in before colon.
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to declare the variable, it should be:

```
for each (var target:Target in targets) {
    // …
}
```

Note the `var`.